# My super is not working even though I think its set up right

Tags: java, syntax-error, super

I'm doing an assignment for school and im implementing a super but its not working yet i feel its done right. anyone have any idea why my super gives me a syntax error. It tells me "The Constructor Employee(String, String, String) is undefined yet it is though.

Here's my employee class that my other classes extend off of which have this super error.

```
/**
* Abstract class Employee - write a description of the class here
*
* @author (your name here)
* @version (version number or date here)
*/
public abstract class Employee
{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String socialSecurityNumber;

   public Employee(String first, String last, String ssn)
   {
       firstName=first;
       lastName=last;
       socialSecurityNumber=ssn;
   }

   public abstract double earnings();

   public String toString()
   {
       return("\n"+firstName+" "+lastName+
               "\nsocial security number: "+ socialSecurityNumber);
   }
}
```

Here's one class with the super that gives me the issue.

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee{
    private double weeklySalary;

    // four-argument constructor
    public SalariedEmployee(String first, String last, String ssn, double salary) {
        super(first, last, ssn); // pass to Employee constructor
        setWeeklySalary(salary); // validate and store salary
    } // end four-argument SalariedEmployee constructor

    // set salary
    public void setWeeklySalary(double salary) {
        weeklySalary = salary < 0.0 ? 0.0 : salary;
    } // end method setWeeklySalary

    // return salary
    public double getWeeklySalary() {
        return weeklySalary;
    } // end method getWeeklySalary

    // calculate earnings; override abstract method earnings in Employee
    public double earnings() {
        return getWeeklySalary();
    } // end method earnings

    // return String representation of SalariedEmployee object
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("salaried employee: %s\n%s: $%,.2f",
            super.toString(), "weekly salary", getWeeklySalary());
    } // end method toString
 } // end class SalariedEmployee
```

My other two classes like i said have the same issue so i don't think it would be necessary to post them but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you have recompiled `Employee`.

Comment: posted codes are compiling without errors... best bet is recompiling, as Elliot already suggested (eventually after deleting *.class files). Maybe adding to question how files are being compiled (and whole error message) can help....((and assuming you've not wrote something like  `public void Employee(String first, ...`))

Comment: What do your packages and imports look like? Is the `Employee` class that you're extending in `SalariedEmployee` the one you are _intending_ to extend, or another one with the same name but in a different package?

Comment: I don't know the context of this, but I would never put SSN in toString(). The value of toString() is likely to be stored in log files at some point, so you would have a name, ssn and maybe even salary all being written to a place that may not be being protected very well. That said if this is a school project or similar with test data there would be no harm.

Answer (score 1):

That may happens if you have another Employee class defined somewhere else in your project (could be in one of your .java file in the same package, some imports or in the classpath).

Your call to super(first, last, ssn) is all good. You may try to compile the two files in command line to confirm the above:

```
javac Employee.java SalariedEmployee.java
```